# Magento2: Move Order Total Excl. Tax after the Shipping amount in Order Summary in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-summary

I want to move **order total excl. tax** after the **shipping amount** in order summary.

[image]

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i achieved it. Move element is not possible for it so i found another way.

I created a new module like

> app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\registration.php

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                        <item name="some_text" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">35</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/subTotal</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>

                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\subTotal.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
], function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
    'use strict';


    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/subtotal'
        },
        totals: quote.getTotals(),

        getGrandTotalExclTax: function () {
            var total = this.totals();

            if (!total) {
                return 0;
            }

            return this.getFormattedPrice(total['grand_total']);
        }
    });
});
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\template\subtotal.html

```
<tr class="order_total">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Order Total Excl. VAT' "></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="label" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax() "></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can manage it from admin

```
Path : Store > Config > Sales > Sales > Checkout Totals Sort Order
```

[image]

Comment: i just want to move the order total excl. tax not whole grand total.